# pyside application crahes on QMenu.exec_

Tags: python, windows, qt, python-3.x, pyside

I reimplemented QTreeWidget to be able to control the right-click menu. I wanted to show the menu only if the right click was on an item.

When my app calls nodeMenu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos()) 
The whole application crashes.

I'm in Windows7 with python 3.3
This is the crash : python.exe has stopped working 
Windows can check online for a solution to the problem. (see complete error at the end)

This is the code (edited)

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class LTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.handleHeaderMenu)

    def handleHeaderMenu(self, pos):

        item = self.itemAt(pos)
        if item:
            nodeMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.parent);
            deleteNode = QtGui.QAction("Delete node",self.parent)
            nodeMenu.addAction(deleteNode)
            #self.mapToGlobal(pos))
            nodeMenu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

        else:
            return

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Inherited class constructor
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # ...

        # TreeView Widget
        self.tree_widget = LTreeWidget()
        self.tree_widget.headerItem().setText(0, "Objects")

        item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree_widget)
        item.setText(0, "Cube ")

        '''
        # TreeView Menu Policy
        self.tree_widget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)

        # TreeView Menu Definition
        nodeMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.tree_widget);
        deleteNode = QtGui.QAction("Delete node",nodeMenu)
        self.tree_widget.addAction(deleteNode)
        '''

        # TreeView Scaling Policy
        treePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        treePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        self.tree_widget.setSizePolicy(treePolicy)
        #...
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.tree_widget)

        # Set Layout
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    # ...

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Complete crash message

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    51606889
  Fault Module Name:    QtGui4.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.8.2.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4fa6d7c9
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00357388
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    4105
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine for me. Only thing I found is you need to add the action to the menu, not the widget (replace `self.addAction(deleteNode)` with `nodeMenu.addAction(deleteNode)`)

Comment: Good catch, I've modified the code but it still crashes.
I've added the simplest program to reproduce. Right click on the item and it should crash.

Comment: Have you considered updating `PySide`? You're probably using a outdated version (the latest comes with Qt 4.8.5 - and with that I can't reproduce, could be a bug).

Comment: You're right.
I was using PySide 1.1.2 and I updated to 1.2.1. Now it works!

Thanks